# What does the "AndroidRuntime START" log message mean?

Tags: android, android-runtime

I've seen the following log message near a few crashes I'm working on:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

What exactly does this mean? Obviously means the "AndroidRuntime" is starting, but what is that? I thought it meant my app is starting but I don't see it every time I start my app. What ***exactly*** is starting?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You use `unhandled exception handler`?

Comment: @deathember I don't know. Why?

Comment: Because only he can change stacktrace error message..

Comment: @deathember this has nothing to do with that.  It's not an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that an instance of the virtual machine is being started up in a new process.

Typically this happens in *at least* three cases:

1) When the system itself starts up and starts a process with a vm to be "zygote" - the parent of all app processes.  Subsequently, apps **do not** restart this from scratch, rather they get already-initialized processes forked off of zygote, so you would only see the message from this if the device reboots or the android framework restarts.

2) When the system starts up the vm *from scratch* in a special mode to dexopt and otherwise process a freshly installed apk

3) When various tools start up a temporary instance of the vm to run compiled-from java code to access certain java-only APIs.  For example, "am start" does this to fire an intent, and that is likely involved in starting a newly installed application for testing.

It's possible it also happens for similar reasons subsequent to some types of crash if one of the reporting tools to be run incorporates java code and is not a child of zygote.